# On RPi Zero, garbage received using g_printer gadget

Tags: pi-zero-w, gadget

I have a RPi Zero W as a printer gadget, and it shows up as a printer on my Macbook (solved here in comments https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/408293/how-to-make-g-printer-usb-gadget-printer-work-in-raspberian-pi?noredirect=1#comment731094_408293). I have it set on the Mac as an Epson 9-pin (a very basic printer).

If I send data from my Macbook with `lp -d linux_g_printer some_text_file.txt` and listen on the RPi as `sudo cat /dev/g_printer0` the RPi receives garbage characters.

Is the `lp` operation trashing the text due to the driver?
Is the `cat` operation not appropriate to listen?
How do I test the interface and send data?

Comment: Did you try `strings /dev/g_printer0`

Comment: The file I'm sending is a readme text file so it should be text except for newlines. Running `strings` on the file on the Macbook displays the lines of the file. Running it on the RPi displays nothing. It looks like the data arriving at `g_printer0` is being corrupted (or modified) so mostly non-printable data (binary) is being returned, and thus no output from strings. It's like a classical serial port baud rate problem, but that should not apply here.

Comment: Try setting the output of the Mac to "raw" ... MacOSx uses CUPS... in fact,  Apple is the vendor of CUPS...  you can probably change many of the more advanced printer settings through the CUPS web interface at `http://localhost:631`

Comment: Fantastic! That worked.